# Could not locate build.gradle used for Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, testfairy

When i try to build version with **TestFairy** Android Studio throws this error: TestFairy: Could not locate build.gradle used for Android project. Maybe one of you have been facing with this problem before and know how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

remove the colon from the includes

before:

```
settings.gradle
include ":app"
include "CordovaLib"
```

after:

```
settings.gradle
include "app"
include "CordovaLib"
```